# Terminating running thread c++ std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to run a thread that does something as simple as this:

```
main(){
    std::thread  thread_pulse([=]{
        *this->do_adress = true;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
        *this->do_adress = false;
        //delete this thread to avoid memory leaks
    });
    //do some other stuff without waiting for the thread to terminate
}
```

how do I assure that when the thread execution is done the thread deleted and there are no memory leaks without waiting for the thread to finish execution on main?

EDIT:

thanks for the help, whith the help this worked as I wanted

```
main(){
    std::thread ([=]{
        *this->do_adress = true;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
        *this->do_adress = false;
        //delete this thread to avoid memory leaks
    }).detach;
    //do some other stuff without waiting for the thread to terminate
}
```

Comment: `std::thread thread_pulse(...); thread_pulse.detach();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure the thread is done before you exit `main` then right before you return from `main` use

```
thread_pulse.join();
```

This will wait for `thread_pulse` to finish before continuing on.

If you do not care if the thread finishes then you can `detach` it like

```
thread_pulse.detach();
```

after you create it.  This will let program end without an exception being thrown.

---

Alternatively you could build a wrapper class that stores the thread and when it gets destroyed it will call `join` or `detach` for you so you do not have to remember.  You can use something like [Scott Myers ThreadRAII](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/12/threadraii-thread-suspension-trouble.html)

> ```
> class ThreadRAII 
> {     
> public:     
>     ThreadRAII(std::thread&& thread): t(std::move(thread)) {}
>    ~ThreadRAII() { if (t.joinable()) t.join(); }
> private:    
>     std::thread t;    
> };
> ```

And either modify to let you pick whether to `join()` or `detach()` or just hard code the behavior.

Comment: I actually wanted a detach. thanks, I'll edit the question for future reference

Comment: @heczaco No problem.  Glad to help.